# Java .jar gives "The handle is invalid" message but running program in Netbeans does not

Tags: java

Java .jar gives "The handle is invalid" message but running program in Netbeans does not. Any ideas where to begin would be helpful. This programs moves databases from one IP to another.

```
 private String[] readSourceFile() {
        //This method returns an array of strings to populate the IP drop down list
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        String strLine;
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("SourceIPlist.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                arr.add(strLine);
            }
            in.close();
            br.close();
            fstream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ei) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ei.getMessage());
        }
        return arr.toArray(new String[arr.size()]);

    }
```

Comment: You’ll need to be more specific.  What does “gives a message” even mean?  Does a dialog pop up in the center of your screen?  Are you seeing it in a log?  Is an exception occurring?  Is that text present anywhere in the source code?

Comment: Sorry, here's some more info. A java style dialog pops up before the program appears saying "The handle is invalid". You click "OK" then the program functions as normal. When running in NetBeans I never see this message. I don't see any exceptions, I'm catching and displaying all of them to the user. And no, the text is not present in the source code.

Comment: A search turned up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150039/java-io-ioexception-the-handle-is-invalid.  Make sure you are not closing any files or sockets or database connections until you’re done using them.

Comment: Yeah, I read that one earlier. Thinking its something with the files used to populate the combo boxes since it's not establishing a connection until a button is pressed and the message appears right when the program is started.  But then again my first version had the same code for the combo boxes and this message didn't appear.I will look again tomorrow and report back.   Thanks.

Comment: Added code above. So I commented out my methods that read files and the message stopped. I tried moving the fstream and br ahead of the try but then it says I'm not catching the exceptions. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In your `JOptionPane.showMessageDetail`, don't pass `ex.getMessage()` - instead, just pass `ex.toString()`. (Same for `ei`.) Then you'll get more detail about the exception that is being thrown.

Comment: What is `in`? You only need to close the `BufferedReader`, and you are leaking it in the case of an `IOException`.

Comment: If you managed to fix your problem, by all means add an **answer** with your solution, but don't edit your question to add "Solved" to the title, or adding the solution to your **question**. I have rolled back your last edit.

Comment: The easiest solution is to replace the entire method with [Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-).  Something like:  `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("SourceIPList.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the in.close(); call and the message stopped. I picked that up from some example I came across. I assumed it closed all the inputs (fstream, br) at once. Now I'm thinking the in.close(); was making an anonymous object or something? Thoughts?

Below are the details for the method.

public void close() throws IOException
Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.
The close method of InputStream does nothing.
Throws:
IOException - if an I/O error occurs.

Comment: The variable `in` is not declared anywhere in the code you've shown in your question, so we don't know *what* it is. It does not appear to be related to `fstream` or `br` at all.

Comment: Its not defined in my code. I right clicked and navigated to declaration. It brought up a System.java tab and highlighted the following.     /**
         * The "standard" input stream. This stream is already
         * open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream
         * corresponds to keyboard input or another input source 
    specified by
         * the host environment or user.
         */
        public final static InputStream in = null;

Comment: That's `System.in`. The standard input stream. You closed it, and something, somewhere, tried to read input from the keyboard after you closed it. That's why you got "Invalid handle". I don't understand why you had `in.close()` in your code in the first place if you weren't sure what it did.

Comment: As I said earlier "I picked that up from some example I came across. I assumed it closed all the inputs (fstream, br) at once." I don't read the source code for everything if I think I understand what it does. Anyway, thanks for the help from everyone.