# Exception in thread "DisconnectableInputStream source reader" org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid

Tags: java, gradle, octopus-deploy, ml-gradle

I'm running gradle (v. 5.2.1) deployment of Marklogic (ml-gradle plugin) via Octopus deploy app. Tentacle runs as Local System. I'm running it through .net application runner which spawns gradle command.

On my dev environment it works fine, but on production it fails every time. I've tried running it from cmd as NT Authority\System but it didn't fail. I've even tried running Calamari.exe with --run-script.

Do you have any ideas where to search for problems?

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "DisconnectableInputStream source reader" org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
   at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
   at org.gradle.util.DisconnectableInputStream$1.run(DisconnectableInputStream.java:125)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
   at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
   at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
   at org.gradle.util.DisconnectableInputStream$1.run(DisconnectableInputStream.java:96)
   ... 1 more
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150039/java-io-ioexception-the-handle-is-invalid

Comment: @AkashShah thanks Akash, but it's not an exception in my code.